# knappen and beccari font naming conventions

Tags: fonts, naming

Karl Berry's font naming convention is well documented and fully available; but while trying to hack a couple of fonts by Jörg Knappen (EC/T1) and Claudio Beccari (CB/LGR), I am having trouble to figure out the cryptic code leading to their font names in the narrow space of a 8.3 file name. It is obvious that the trailing number is the size, but what do the letters mean? A summary and a pointer to documentation on this matter is surely welcome.

---

Clarification.

In Berry's scheme, it's easy to say what `fcmr8y` or `fccr6t` stand for, given the criteria established in `fontname.pdf`; but the meaning of `gmmn` in cbgreek or `eccc` in ecfonts is not that clear to me.

In the documentation for EC fonts (`dcdoc.tex`, still calling the fonts `dc`), it states:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item The first two letters (either \texttt{dc} or \texttt{tc} denote
      the encoding and the general design of the font.
\item The one or two following letters denotes the family, shape, and 
      series attributes of the font. E.\,g. \texttt{r} for roman, 
      \texttt{bx} for bold extended, \texttt{ti} for text italic, or
      \texttt{bi} for bold extended italic. A complete overview is given 
      at the end of this section.
\item The following four digits give the design size in \TeX's points
      multiplied with 100. E.\,g \texttt{1000} denotes tex point,
      \texttt{1440} denotes magstep 2, i.\,e. 14.4 point, and
      \texttt{0500} denotes five point.
\end{itemize}
```

but I can't find this promised "complete overview".

In a similar way, the documentation for `cbgreek` in `cbfonts-fd` mentions in the code

```
19 \EC@family{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{ui} {grxu}
20 \EC@family{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{li} {grxl}
21 \EC@family{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{rs} {gmxn}
22 \EC@family{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{ro} {gmxo}
23 \EC@family{LGR}{cmr}{b}{li} {grbl}
```

but what do `gmxn` or `grbl` stand for, is left unexplained, if I am not missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: I typeset the dc documentation (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ec/src, the file is dcdoc.tex), and it is crystal clear; where to find the document was not so... my apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the font definition files](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/fonts/greek/cbfonts-fd/cbfonts-fd.pdf) and [the font family names](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/fonts/greek/cbfonts/cbgreek.pdf), with a little bit of filling in the blanks ourselves, we see:

1. `g` = CB Greek
2. A font family:

   - `r` - regular, or what the `cbgreek` documentation calls “Didot” style
   - `o` - outline
   - `m` = what the `cbgreek` documentation calls “roman serifs”
   - `s` = sans serif
   - `t` = typewriter
   - `l` = LXfonts-style, or “slide fonts”
3. A series, encoding both weight and width. (Except for the slide fonts.) The series are:

   - `m` = medium
   - `b` = bold non-extended
   - `x` = bold extended
   - `t` = the single series of typewriter fonts
4. If the third letter was a series, the fourth is a shape:

   - `n` = normal/upright
   - `i` = italic
   - `c` = upright small caps
   - `o` = oblique
   - `u` = upright italic
   - `l` = Lipsian
   - `e` and `a` = variant shapes for epsilon, described as “upright” or “oblique.”

The LXfonts-style fonts use the third letter to select a subfamily (sans-serif, typewriter or a variant).

Comment: so, there was indeed some detective work to do: it was not as straightforward as I thought.